# Openbox ArchLinux keybinding CapsLock in RC.xml

Tags: xml, archlinux, window-managers

I got a little problem here with my shortcut definitions for Openbox keyboard actions.
I want to use the caps lock key as a prefix to perform a shortcut.

I thought I'll remap the capslock key to the hyper key, done by
`setxkbmap -option caps:hyper`

Output from xev **before** swapping caps and hyper:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0xf6, subw 0x0, time 2262248, (-560,518), root:(585,681),
    state 0x2, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe5, Caps_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Output from xev **after** swapping caps and hyper:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0xf6, subw 0x0, time 2364568, (-112,127), root:(1033,290),
    state 0x40, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffed, Hyper_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Alright, so far, so good. Defining an action with the Hyper Key in RC.xml, like:

```
</keybind>
<keybind key="H-x">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>gmrun</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

works actually!

But, when I use the super key and push x gmrun gets executed as well. In some way, the super key works as hyper as well. Hmm, is that the right assumption or what do I miss here?

Btw, here the xev output from Super so it's obviously a different key.

```
KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0xf6, subw 0x0, time 2657169, (-294,402), root:(851,565),
    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Well, I noticed the keycode from caps lock didn't change after using the setxkbmap command. In both conditions its  keycode 66 (even after `setxkbmap -option caps:none`).

Relying on http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings#Keys it's actually possible to use the key code, I changed my RC.xml example to:

```
</keybind>
    <keybind key="0x42-x">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>gmrun</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
```

But this doesn't work at all. Would be nice to use the keycode so no dealing with setxkbmap, but either ways don't know which part I've missed and I'm grateful for every hint guys!
Cheers

EDIT:
Output 'xmodmap with setxkbmap -option caps:hyper'
    xmodmap:  up to 5 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Hyper_L (0x42),  Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: What's the output from `xmodmap`?

Comment: Seems Hyper and Super are listed in the line "mod4".
with setxkbmap -option caps:hyper it is:
xmodmap:  up to 5 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Hyper_L (0x42),  Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)

Comment: Looks so messy as a comment, added it on the end of my first post

Answer (score 1):

Got it working  :)

I've created a key map file, by

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap
```

then I added on the end of ~/.Xmodmap:

```
clear      lock
clear      mod1
clear      mod2
clear      mod3
clear      mod4
clear      mod5
keycode      66 = Hyper_L
add     control = Control_L Control_R
add        mod1 = Alt_L Alt_R Meta_L
add        mod2 = Num_Lock
add        mod3 = Hyper_L
add        mod4 = Super_L Super_R
add        mod5 = Mode_switch ISO_Level3_Shift
```

I executed following command:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:hyper &&  xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

and it works

the new output of xmodmap is,

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Alt_L (0xcc),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        Hyper_L (0x42),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

The only weird thing is openbox takes around 10~15 secs to execute the "xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap" command. The CPU run's up like I'm starting three firefox sessions with each hundred tabs  :o
And if I put the command into ~/.config/openbox/autostart it will mess up my conky panels, seems like a graphical issue.

Comment: There's no need to clear and reset anything you don't intend to change.